# How do execute ALTER TABLE <table> OWNER to <user> in H2 (with Spring Boot) for Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I have a Spring Boot application with an Aurora (Postgresql) DB that I would like to add JPA tests for. We have Flyway setup and our DDL scripts are in a folder in `src/main/resources/...`.

I hooked up H2, but I'm getting a syntax error with ALTER TABLE. It looks like H2 doesn't have the `ALTER TABLE <table> OWNER to <user>` command.

Has anyone seen this before or know a clever way to get around this?

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE <table> [*]OWNER to <user>"; expected "ADD, SET, RENAME, DROP, ALTER"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE <table> OWNER to <user> [42001-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is different between these 2 DBMS.  You can separate them by different executing path via:  (assume you are using liquibase script)

```
<changeSet id="pg-***"  dbms="postgresql">
    content
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="h2-***" dbms="h2">
    content
</changeSet>
```

If you are using Some other 3rdparty libs to populate, I believe there is similar way to separate them.